# Why I cannot create more PictureBox in my array?

Tags: c#

First of all I want to thank you for your time :) So there is my problem.. I am trying to make a little game where I spawn **PictureBox** and send it from right to left and my player which will be a **PictureBox** will try to avoid them jumping. So the first thing I did is , I created my PictureBox spawner with a class .. But the problem is , I can only spawn block[0] .. when I try to create block[1], nothing happens !! Please help me.. There is my code :

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace Game_0._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Block[] block = new Block[50];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int _Length = block.Length;

            for(int i=0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                block[i] = new Block();
                this.Controls.Add(block[i]._ScreenPanel());
                block[i].Screen.Controls.Add(block[i].Box);
                label1.Text = ("Generating block [" + i + "]");

            }    

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            block[0].SpawnBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

**Block.cs**

```
namespace Game_0._1
{
    class Block
    {
        public Panel Screen;
        public PictureBox Box;
        Point x = new Point(50, 50);
        Size s = new Size(150, 50);
        Color c = Color.FromName("black");

        public Block()
        {
            Screen = new Panel();
            Screen.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Box = new PictureBox();

        }
        public Panel _ScreenPanel()
        {
            return Screen;
        }
        public PictureBox SpawnBlock()
        {
            Box.Name = "Obstacle";
            Box.Location = x;
            Box.Size = s;
            Box.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Box.BackColor = c;
            return Box;
        }
        public void ChangeXLoc()
        {
            this.x.X += 50;
        }


    }
}
```

Here :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                block[0].SpawnBlock();
            }
```

this spawn a black box successfully , but if I type block[1], nothing ...

Comment: Do you mean to say that changing the `Click` event to do this `block[1].SpawnBlock();` does not work?

Comment: I would suggest keeping your object model entirely separate from your view model. Blocks shouldn't contain PictureBox objects. Your view should manage how it renders Blocks. Also, your click handler only handles the first element in your array. Nothing will happen with block[1], unless you code it that.

Comment: No the click event is working fine :o I even added a little MessageBox to make sure..  Problem is , only the array[0] has something in it and actually create a pictureBox .. I dont understand why..

Comment: Well there's your issue, when you click you are only creating a box in element `0` of `block`, therefore only that element will have anything in it. If you wish to make all 50 boxes, you will have to loop or make a method that creates all 50 from the click

Comment: Well I thought my loop in my Public Form1(); would do that !! I just tried to make a timer :

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            block[1] = new Block();
            this.Controls.Add(block[1]._ScreenPanel());
            block[1].Screen.Controls.Add(block[1].Box);
            block[1].SpawnBlock();
        }
and its not working :/

Comment: your 'public void ChangeXLoc()' is maybe wrong? it looks like your always have the same position for the box!

Comment: Oh I am not using the ChangeXLoc ^^ if I delete everything in my button event or timer and change it for block[1], its just empty xd

Comment: @Joh. Good point, on that note should it not be the panel that is moved along by 50 in X? If not, then the issue could also be that the panel of the first box is overlapping any other boxes' panels

Comment: @Alfie The problem was the Panel !! I made a second panel from the Designer and it worked.. I guess I will just create 1 panel trough designer and not from code ^^ Thanks !! I couldn't fix it without your help :)

Comment: I'm glad, shall I put that as an answer for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `Panel` (Screen) is overlapping the `Panel` that box[1] is positioned in, as a result it is not visible unless brought to front - which will in turn make the other box invisible instead.

A solution to this is to use a single panel, and size it accordingly, this allows you to place each box on the same panel and have their position relative to the **Panel's 0,0**.

Another solution would be to have a panel for each box which is the same size as the box and **move the Panel and not the box** which will have the same effect, but likely require less code to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little maybe it helps:

your form :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Block[] _block = new Block[50];
    private Point _x = new Point(0, 50);
    private  Timer _timer=new Timer();
    private int _index = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            _block[i] = new Block(_x);
             //Move the position of the block
            ChangeXLoc();
            Controls.Add(_block[i]._ScreenPanel());
            label1.Text = @"Generating block [" + i + @"]";
        }
    }
    //Timer to spawn the blocks
    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _block[_index].SpawnBlock();
        if (_index < 49)
            _index++;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void ChangeXLoc()
    {
        _x.X += 50;
    }
}
```

and your block class :

```
class Block
    {
        Panel Screen;
        PictureBox Box;
        Point _x;
        Size s = new Size(50, 50);
        Color c = Color.FromName("black");

       //Pass the position x to the block
        public Block(Point x)
        {
            _x = x;
            Screen = new Panel
            {
                Size = s
            };
        }
        public Panel _ScreenPanel()
        {
            Screen.Location = _x;
            return Screen;
        }

        public void  SpawnBlock()
        {
            Box = new PictureBox
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Name = "Obstacle" + _x,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                BackColor = c
            };
           Screen.Controls.Add(Box);
        }
    }
```